# 100% heigh on div element between 2 static height

Tags: html, css, height

I'm trying to make a div have 100% height. Which is always a pain in the ass...
I want my #wrapper to be 100% and my #middle to be aswell..

```
<div id="wrapper" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:900px;">
    <div id="top" style="height: 100px;width:inherit;">
        This stays top, with static height.
    </div>
    <div id="middle" style="width:inherit;">
        This should take all space that is left in height...
    </div>
    <div id="footer" style="height:50px;width:inherit;">
        This stays in bottom, with static height
    </div>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Xgsz/9)

Comment: Help us to help you with your live demo on jsfiddle.

Comment: Heres a jsfiddle demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/6Xgsz/9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can make it without JS using absolute positioning and a tricky `overflow: auto` :

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%; 
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto; 
    width:500px;
    height: 100%;
}
#top {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
#middle {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    top: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    height:50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top">
        This stays top, with static height.
    </div>
    <div id="middle">
        This should take all space that is left in height...
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        This stays in bottom, with static height
    </div>
</div>
```

Note : use `width: 100%;` instead of `width: inherit;`, which is not supported by IE7

Answer (score 0):

Uhmm you can try something with javascript or jquery if I'm correct.
Don't forget to link jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    //minus 150 because > top = 100px, footer = 50px == 150px
    //offsetHeight gives you the height in pixels from the div "wrapper"
    newHeight = document.getElementById('wrapper').offsetHeight - 150;

    //updates the height of the div #middle
    $("#middle").css({'height' : newHeight});
});
</script>
```

It worked for me ^^